# MySQL - search JSON type row to find open stores

Tags: mysql

I have a table which stores working hours in the **JSON** format. I am trying to find the way to select all stores which are open when the query is made.

This is the example of the stored hours (as stored in the DB, unformated):

```
{"friday-to": "18:00", "monday-to": "18:00", "sunday-to": null, "friday-to2": "06:00", "monday-to2": "06:00", "sunday-to2": null, "tuesday-to": "18:00", "friday-from": "07:00", "monday-from": "07:00", "saturday-to": "15:00", "sunday-from": null, "thursday-to": "18:00", "tuesday-to2": "06:00", "friday-from2": "06:00", "monday-from2": "06:00", "saturday-to2": "06:00", "sunday-from2": null, "thursday-to2": "06:00", "tuesday-from": "07:00", "wednesday-to": "18:00", "saturday-from": "09:00", "thursday-from": "07:00", "tuesday-from2": "06:00", "wednesday-to2": "06:00", "saturday-from2": "06:00", "thursday-from2": "06:00", "wednesday-from": "07:00", "wednesday-from2": "06:00"}
```

Formated for better view:

```
{
    "friday-to": "18:00",
    "monday-to": "18:00",
    "sunday-to": null, 
    "friday-to2": "06:00", 
    "monday-to2": "06:00",
    "sunday-to2": null, 
    "tuesday-to": "18:00", 
    "friday-from": "07:00", 
    "monday-from": "07:00", 
    "saturday-to": "15:00", 
    "sunday-from": null, 
    "thursday-to": "18:00", 
    "tuesday-to2": "06:00", 
    "friday-from2": "06:00", 
    "monday-from2": "06:00", 
    "saturday-to2": "06:00", 
    "sunday-from2": null, 
    "thursday-to2": "06:00", 
    "tuesday-from": "07:00", 
    "wednesday-to": "18:00", 
    "saturday-from": "09:00", 
    "thursday-from": "07:00", 
    "tuesday-from2": "06:00", 
    "wednesday-to2": "06:00", 
    "saturday-from2": "06:00", 
    "thursday-from2": "06:00", 
    "wednesday-from": "07:00", 
    "wednesday-from2": "06:00"
}
```

Currently only the first **-to** is active, the **-to2** is not still relevant.

For example I want to find all stores which are opened on today’s day (currently Tuesday). Is it possible to do this?

Current MySQL version:

```
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.22
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [MySQL manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html) has examples of the function `JSON_EXTRACT` which may be useful.  It indicates you can do something along the lines of:

```
SELECT c, JSON_EXTRACT(c, "$.id"), g
FROM jemp
WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(c, "$.id") > 1
ORDER BY JSON_EXTRACT(c, "$.name");
```

so you may be able to do:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table 
WHERE (
    JSON_EXTRACT(field, "$.tuesday-from") IS NOT NULL
    OR JSON_EXTRACT(field, "$.tuesday-from2") IS NOT NULL
    )
```

Comment: This is what I need. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Glad it works.  It's not something I had tried, it was a more theoretical answer